# Find if in a list of a class defined by me exists an element with given variables values

Tags: java, list, arraylist, methods

I have defined the class User:

```
    public class User
    {
        public String id;
        public String passWord;

        public User(String id, String passWord)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.passWord = passWord;
        }
    }
```

Then I created a list of Users:

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User("u1", "abc"));
    users.add(new User("u2", "aaa"));
    users.add(new User("u3", "bba"));
```

To find the user in the list with a given id and password I did:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("User: ");
String user = input.next();
System.out.print("Password: ");
String pass = input.next();
int N = -1;
for (int n = 0; n < medicos.size(); n++)
{
    if (user.equals(users.get(n).id) && pass.equals(users.get(n).passWord))
        {
            N = n;
        }
    }
```

Is there a simpler way to get the element of the list containing the given id and password, for example like using a method similar to contain?

Comment: You could maybe just use a `Map`/`HashMap`

Comment: Do yourself and the people you are working with the favour of (1) following the convention of using small first letter in variable names (not N) (2) specifically not using n and N for two different variables — some time someone will surely confuse them.

Comment: With a good implementation of `equals()` in `User`, you may use `users.contains(new User(user, pass))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HashMap`. You can still use an `ArrayList` of `User` if you want, but you could also add the username and password to a `HashMap` with the username as the key and the password as the value. So, for instance, you could do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("u1", "abc");
users.put("u2", "aaa");
users.put("u3", "bba");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("User: ");
String user = input.next();
System.out.print("Password: ");
String pass = input.next();

String pword;
if (users.containsKey(user)) {
    pword = users.get(user);
}
```

Now the variable `pword` contains the password for the user named "user" (obtained from the `Scanner`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is in fact a much better way. However, this is part of  an exercise in wich is asked to use lists whenever possible

Comment: @DDDD In that case, you probably won't do any better than iterating through the list and searching for a `User` with the same id as the username retrieved from the `Scanner`. That's what you are currently doing.